# How can I convert Opus-MT models to a tensorflow SavedModel?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, machine-translation

The [Opus-MT project](https://github.com/Helsinki-NLP/Opus-MT) provides a large selection of [pretrained neural translation models](http://opus.nlpl.eu/Opus-MT/).

Opus-MT is based on [Marian-NMT](https://marian-nmt.github.io/), which is a pure C++ codebase closely related to [nematus](https://github.com/EdinburghNLP/nematus). Finally, nematus is based on tensorflow.

For deployment reasons, I would like to convert an Opus-MT model to a tensorflow SavedModel. I have high hopes that this should be possible somehow:

- the pretrained Opus-MT models store layer weights in nicely formatted `.npy` files
- by default, the Marian-NMT commands for training new models create nematus compatible models.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not easily possible.

The RNN-based in Marian still keep the backward compatibility with Nematus models, but with [the legacy version](https://github.com/EdinburghNLP/nematus/tree/theano) implemented in Theano which seems to be no longer maintained. There is no compatibility between Marian and the current TensorFlow version of Nematus.

Models in Opus-MT are Transformers, Transformer was never implemented in the Theano version of Nematus, only in the TensorFlow one.

Marian saves the parameters in a binary format that can be loaded using Numpy. In theory, you can build exactly the same architecture in TensorFlow (I doubt current Nematus will be exactly the same, there will be some minor differences in bracketing operations, some matrices might be transposed, etc.) and assign the parameter values to the TensorFlow variables. But this would be a very tedious job.